# Парсинг даты из DateQuerySet

Tags: python, django

Всем привет.

Есть запрос:

```
test_date = Many.objects.filter(id=id).dates('date', 'month')
```

Есть ответ:

```
[datetime.date(2014, 9, 1)]
```

Как распарсить ответ в вид 2014-9-1?

Comment: А этого мало?:

    cur_date = datetime.date(2014, 9, 1)
    print cur_date # 2014-9-1

Comment: Мало. Мне нужно преобразовать значение из базы, а там не обязательно сегодняшняя дата.

Comment: А при чем здесь сегодняшняя дата? Я нигде акцент на этом не делал. Точно так же можно сделать и для `datetime.date(2010, 1, 1)` - я сам инициализирую, но это для примера, значение может откуда угодно придти.

Comment: А, вроде понял, вас массив смущает? Нут если в result содержится [datetime.date(2014, 9, 1)], то получить содержимое можно же так: result[0] или я опять не понял?

Comment: Спсибо! isoformat() формат помог.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в ответе теоретически может быть несколько дат.

Если вы хотите получить только одну, берите, допустим, первую:

```
if test_date:
    print test_date[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Если все - попробуйте так:

```
print [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in test_date]
```

Если обязательно нужен формат без нулей - попробуйте маску %Y-%-m-%-d

Comment: Ну, судя по фильтру, вернется только одна запись.

А вот почему некоторые берутся за фреймворк, не зная основ, - загадка...

Даже если приходится работать с готовым кодом, то ведь можно хотя бы недельку потратить на основы, а уж потом в бой рваться...

Comment: Точно. Не заметил filter. Но тогда и dates использовать бессмысленно...

Comment: Готового кода у меня нет. Сижу делаю свою систему ради практики. Многое нахожу сам, но некоторое, хоть и самое простое, иногда не найти не получается.

Comment: @balalay: [`"%Y-%-m-%-d"` формат не документирован в Питоне](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), т.е., strftime(3), зависимая от платформы используется. [POSIX тоже не поддерживает этот формат (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html), но на моей системе с glibc он работает. Чтобы прочитать обратно (strptime(): string -> datetime), другой формат нужен: `'%Y-%m-%d'`.